# Trouble hooking blocks with theme templates

Tags: theming, blocks

So I am making blocks and viewing the page source when they're displayed, and for instance one has the id="block-views-first-row-footer-links-block"

so I make templates called the following: none will work(yes I am clearing the cache)...I am using drupal 7.12

block--views-first-row-footer-links.tpl.php

block--first-row-footer-links.tpl.php

block--footer-links.tpl.php

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For the record, the id assigned to the wrapping div of a block does not necessarily have any relationship to the naming conventions you would use for block templates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a easier way to do this using [Block theme](http://drupal.org/project/blocktheme). But in case you do not want to use it, you can create block template files in the following order.

block--module--delta.tpl.php

block--module.tpl.php

block--region.tpl.php

More information can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

Comment: does this "block--views-first-row-footer-links.tpl.php" not follow that format? The blocks--module--delta one?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Is views-first-row-footer-links the name of your module? The best thing right now would be to try the third option. For e.g in block--footer-links.tpl.php, do you have a region named footer-links?